# awk: filter out lins that have either 0, "--", or "NC"

Tags: csv, filter, awk

My tab-delimited file contains many lines, and I want to filter out those lines that have 0, --, or "NC". I'm using this awk code:

```
awk '{for (i=5; i<=14; ++i) if($i !=0 && $i !="--" && $i !="NC") {print;next}}'
```

to filter out, from column 5 through column 14.

I am not sure if this is the right code for my purpose. Could some expert check my code please? Thanks

Comment: The "next" is unneeded or even harmful, the others seem okay.

Comment: For clarity, can you please provide sample input data and show us the results you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to skip lines that contain `0`, `--` or `NC` in fields 5 through 14, you probably meant to do the following. Your existing code is going to print a line every time it encounters anything other than `0`, `--` or `NC` in fields 5 through 14

```
awk '{for (i=5; i<=14; ++i) if($i == 0 || $i == "--" || $i == "NC"){next}};{print}'
```

Comment: **+1**, now that the typo is fixed, this looks right to me. Short form: you can also use `1` in place of `;{print}`, since `1` evaluates to "true", and the default action is to print the line.

Comment: Also, typo alert: `$i = = "--"`

Comment: thanks @ghoti, janos, typo fixed. I tend to prefer an explicit `print` to `1` but to each his own.